# Facebook Connect for iOS auto signs out after quitting app

Tags: iphone, session, facebook

I have implemented Facebook Connect in my app, and it seems to work fine. I can publish statuses and everything. However, when I quit the app and run it again, the session token seems to have expired or something, because I can't post anymore. But if I authenticate with Facebook again, it shows that permissions have already been granted, then only when the callback to the app is called, can I post again.

What am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should store the accessToken and expireTime of your Facebook object yourself. Restore it after startup and verify via isSessionValid, otherwise reauthorize user. You can use these functions for it:

Call the store function within your fbDidLogin, and the restore function whenever it is appropriate after startup of your app.

```
-(void)restoreFBAccessToken {
    self.facebook.accessToken    = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"fb_accessToken"];
    self.facebook.expirationDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"fb_expirationDate"];
}
-(void)storeFBAccessToken {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:self.facebook.accessToken forKey:@"fb_accessToken"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:self.facebook.expirationDate forKey:@"fb_expirationDate"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using FB Connect in my own app, but in an indirect way. I use it through a third-party open source kit named ShareKit. http://www.getsharekit.com/

As I remember, ShareKit does the job pretty well. It remembers those login information even though the app is shut down.

Since ShareKit is open-source, I suggest you take a look at its code. It should have an answer for you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure to start the session once again when the app is reloaded up?

Comment: i hav facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId: in viewDidLoad: but it's still not working..

Comment: I think there's also a [session start]; or something similar you might have to call.